# cannot find symbol in grails quartz 2 - grails asynchronous mail plugin?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

Compilation problem while starting the project

```
java\grails\plugin\quartz2\GrailsJobFactory.java:49: cannot find symbol
    symbol  : method newJob(org.quartz.spi.TriggerFiredBundle,org.quartz.Scheduler)
    location: class org.quartz.simpl.PropertySettingJobFactory
                return super.newJob(bundle,scheduler);
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just [download](http://quartz-scheduler.org/downloads/catalog) Quartz 2 Jar file and place it in "Lib" folder which will fix this compilation issue

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the async mail plugin requires the [Quartz2 plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/quartz2), whereas the [quartz monitor plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/quartz-monitor) requires Quartz (one).

You didn't say that you had installed the quartz monitor, but I suspect you did, or some other plugin that requires quartz (one).

What I did was rolled back to 0.4 of the async mail plugin, which uses Quartz (one), and that solved the problem for me.

Comment: actually Quartz 1 comes with lib folder which had the JAR file.

Comment: But for Quartz2 we need to download the Jar file separately and keep it in lib folder